# Python how to convert datetime.date to the YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have a two million timestamp data. I am trying to find first and last date that to in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format so I can use them in saving file name. But, I found out that `np.unique(df.index)` is fast (10s) and produces dates in the
`datetime.date(2022, 6, 7)` format but `df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').unique()` gives the output I want but it takes more than 5 min, which is bad.  So, I decided to use the former approach.

So, How do I convert something like `datetime.date(2022, 6, 7)` to`'2022-06-07'`?

Comment: Why the pandas and numpy tags? What's the relation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35018252/202168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put that into the `str(...)` function:

```py
import datetime
my_date = datetime.date(2022, 6, 7)
print(str(my_date))  # prints 2022-06-07
```

Technically, you can just `print` it and not make it a string first. But putting it in `str` means that instead of printing it, you could save that string to a variable.

If you need more advanced formatting options, then you can do what @FObersteiner suggested. But the format you want happens to be the default, so this will do if you just want that one format

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# import datetime module
from datetime import datetime
  
# consider date in string format
my_date = "30-May-2020-15:59:02"
  
# convert datetime string into date,month,day and
# hours:minutes:and seconds format using strptime
d = datetime.strptime(my_date, "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M:%S")
  
# convert datetime format into %Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S
# format using strftime
print(d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"))
```